# How to display and hide table on button click in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a view controller. In view there is button "show/hide". When I click on this button table should display and when I click on this button again table should hide.

I'm using following code:

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    buttonclk=TRUE;
    if (buttonclk==TRUE)
    {
        [self addTableView];
        buttonclk=FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        tableView1.hidden=YES;
    }
}

-(void)addTableView
{
    CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0,176,320,500);

    tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:fr style:
                  UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    tableView1.delegate = self;
    tableView1.dataSource = self;
    tableView1.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView1];
}
```

When I use this code table is displaying but not hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (tableView1.hidden)    {
       tableView1.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        tableView1.hidden=YES;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should add table in your viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
        //toggle style
        tableView1.hidden=!tableView1.hidden; 
}
```